# Cannot isolate $y$ since it is inside an argument to $e$

Tags: numerical-methods, exponential-function, numerical-optimization

For the following equation, I have been able to solve for $A$ and $B$ using non-linear least squares (implemented by SciPy's [`curve_fit`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) function. It's easy because $y$ has been isolated. I just give the function a few known $(x_k,y_k)$ pairs and the algorithm can then solve for $A$ and $B$ iteratively. $C_0$ is a known constant.

$$
y = Axe^{\frac{xB}{C_0}}
$$

But what happens when $y$ is inside the argument to $e$? How do you go about solving this equation?

$$
y = Axe^{(x-y)\frac{B}{C_0}}
$$

A pointer to some numerical technique would be nice. I am particularly looking for examples using SciPy solvers.

Comment: Look up _Newton's Method_ - it tends to have excellent convergence.  Note that by taking logs, your second equation can also be written as $y=x-(\frac{C_0}{B})(\ln y-\ln(Ax))$, which is sometimes more amenable to numeric solution.

Comment: Thanks for the response @StevenStadnicki. I'm only familiar with Newton's Method when I want to find $x$ when $y=0$ (single variable). Along those lines, I could tell Scipy something like $f(A,B) = x - \left( \frac{C_0}{B} \right)\ln\frac{y}{Ax} - y$. Since I have several known $(x,y)$ pairs, the question I should be asking is: minimize $f(A,B)$ at the known $(x,y)$ pairs by numerically solving for $A$ and $B$. Am I on the right track? What would be a nice Google search term for what I want to do?

Answer (score 1):

From a formal point of view, the problem is quite interesting since $$y = Axe^{k(x-y)}\implies y e^{ky}=Axe^{kx}\implies ky e^{ky}=Akxe^{kx}$$ and using [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), this reduces to $$y=\frac{W\left(A k x e^{k x}\right)}{k}$$ which would require nonlinear regression which requires "reasonable" estimates of parameters $A,k$.

These parameters could easily be obtained writing $$\log(y)=\log(A)+\log(x)+k(x-y)\implies \log\left(\frac y x \right)=\log(A)+k(x-y)$$ So, for each of the $(x_i,y_i)$ data points, define $z_i=\log\left(\frac {y_i} {x_i} \right)$,  $t_i=x_i-y_i$ and the linearized regression model is $$z=a+k t$$ from which $a=\log(A)$ and $k$ are easily obtained.

For illustration purposes, let us play with the following data points (they contain some significant noise).
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
x_i & y_i & z_i & t_i \\
 5 & 2 & -0.916291 & 3 \\
 6 & 3 & -0.693147 & 3 \\
 7 & 4 & -0.559616 & 3 \\
 8 & 4 & -0.693147 & 4 \\
 9 & 5 & -0.587787 & 4 \\
 10 & 6 & -0.510826 & 4 \\
 11 & 6 & -0.606136 & 5 \\
 12 & 7 & -0.538997 & 5 \\
 13 & 8 & -0.485508 & 5 \\
 14 & 8 & -0.559616 & 6 \\
 15 & 9 & -0.510826 & 6
\end{array}
\right)$$

The linear regression leads to $$z=-0.890857+0.0653653 x$$ corresponding to $A=0.410304$ and $k=0.0653653$.

From here, we can start the nonlinear regression with Lambert function. After a few iterations, we should obtain $A=0.42601$ and $k=0.0597227$ corresponding to $R^2=0.9976$ (which is quite good).

The next table compare the original data and the values from the curve fit 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
x_i & y_i & y_i^{calc} \\
 5 & 2 & 2.47652 \\
 6 & 3 & 3.04873 \\
 7 & 4 & 3.64390 \\
 8 & 4 & 4.26083 \\
 9 & 5 & 4.89834 \\
 10 & 6 & 5.55527 \\
 11 & 6 & 6.23048 \\
 12 & 7 & 6.92290 \\
 13 & 8 & 7.63148 \\
 14 & 8 & 8.35523 \\
 15 & 9 & 9.09322
\end{array}
\right)$$

As you can see, the final values of the parameters are quite different from the initial ones. This is normal because what is measured is $y_i$ and not $\log\left(\frac {y_i} {x_i} \right)$.

**Edit**

The problem could, in a similar way, be extended to $$y=A x^a e^{b x+ c y}$$ for which the analytical solution would be $$y=-\frac{W\left(-A c x^a e^{b x}\right)}{c}$$ To obtain estimates of the parameters, write $$\log(y)=\log(A)+a \log(x)+ b x + c y$$ which is again a linear regression. Once the parameters have been obtained, then a nonlinear regression can be launched.

Answer (score 0):

Let u = x-y. Then the equation becomes 
$x-u = A*x*e^{u*B/C_0}$, thus
$u = x-A*x*e^{u*B/C_0}$, 
$u = x*(1-A*e^{u*B/C_0})$,
and then 
$x = {u \over {1-A*e^{u*B/C_0}}}$
Use this equation as a replacement and it should work